# Ухо и серьга — этимологически однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Являются ли слова ухо и серьга этимологически однокоренными?

Comment: Серьга (упрощённо) представляет собой кольцо. Внутренний контур кольца аналогично игольному можно назвать ушком. По своему устройству древняя кольчуга  (цепь)— явление многократно их объединяющее.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать. Исследователи расходятся во мнениях по поводу этимологии этого слова. Много версий рассмотрено в словаре Фасмера (статья **серьга** занимает полстраницы этого словаря), остальные словари либо не содержат этого слова, либо дают отдельные версии из Фасмера. Сам Фасмер придерживается варианта заимствования из древне-чувашского (от слова "кольцо"); Трубачёв в комментариях отмечает, что более вероятно заимствование из тюркского (точное значение слова в тюркском я не смог найти). Несколько версий заимствования из тех языков, в которых слово означало **ушные подвески** Фасмер либо уверенно отрицает, либо приводит в качестве дополнительных версий со ссылками на источники.